# What is the difference between an IQueryable's Contains() and an IEnumerable's Contains()?

Tags: linq, ienumerable, iqueryable, iequalitycomparer

I have an `IQueryable` custs, a `Customer` cust, a `CustomerComparer` custCp which implements `IEqualityComparer`.

When I call `custs.Contains(cust, custCp)` I get an exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Contains'
```

But when I call `custs.AsEnumerable().Contains(cust,custCp)` it works. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operation on an `IQueryable` (in the case of Linq to Entities) is translated to SQL and executed in the database. Since you have an `IEqualityComparer` written in C#, the comparer can't be translated to SQL and the overload can't be supported.

When you translate it to an `IEnumerable` using `AsEnumerable()`, all the data is transferred from the database to memory, where the overload can be easily supported. The downside of course being that you're transferring more data than necessary (potentially the whole table) to have it filtered in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the understandable answer :)

Comment: Yeah that was obvious

Answer (score 1):

`IQueryable` is implemented by query providers and *under the hood* translated into something the target system can understand. For example, `IQueryable.Contains` might be translated to a `x IN y` SQL expression.

On the other hand, `IEnumerable` is not translated like that. Its `Contains` works on anything that implements `IEnumerable` properly.

Using the `IQueryable` operators are executed server-side and therefore will gain you some performance as the query is executed remotely, whereas `IEnumerable` is executed locally (client-side). This means that if you were to get a database table, convert it to enumerable and then apply `Contains` on it, *the whole table* needs to be downloaded to your computer to be enumerated.